# Recognition Day! Thank you to all the users who have continued to make this site possible!

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, thanks

MMSE has helped so many researchers over the last ~3.5 years, and a large part of this was made possible by the users that have [voted on so many of our posts](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate). Also, seeing how many of our avid users visit the site [almost every day](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) helps to remind us that the efforts that we made to get this site launched, and to continue maintaining it and helping it grow, are very much worth it.

Everyone that has upvoted content, posted high-quality questions or answers, helped with peer-review and editing typos, [shared our content in other places](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), or even just contributing to the positive environment here with positive comments on posts or in chat, is very highly appreciated!!! We have [almost 1000 members with 10+ points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPqtT.png) and [more than 2000 members with more than 103+ points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FbFo.png), and I won't try to name all of them here, but I would like to recognize all the exceptional people here that have earned the [**gold** elctorate](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge and continued to consistently contribute content on this site:

## Tyberius

Let's start with [Tyberius](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/7/tyberius) who in addition to fulfilling his duties as a diamond moderator on both this site and on Chemistry.SE, has consistently maintained the [#2 spot for most voting](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) and also the [#2 spot for most editing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all), and on top of that, he has written posts on MMSE during almost every month since this site was first created! Without Tyberius, this site would not be held together as much as it is.

## Camps

[Camps](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/24/camps) has also consistently  maintained the [#3 spot for most voting](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all), has consistently remained in the [top 10 for most editing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all), and just wait for this: Camps has answered a question in every single month since this site was created, except for in March 2022 and June 2023, WOW! Camps is an expert in so many of the topics that I'm not, and therefore helps glue this diverse site togeher.

## S R Maiti

[S R Maiti](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/1380/s-r-maiti?tab=profile) is our newest user to receive the [gold electorate](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge for his exemplary voting practices, but stands out above the rest of our users with that badge because just like Tyberius and Camps, he has written a post in almost every month since joining the site (only having missed 4 months in 2022, the same amount that Tyberius missed in 2023, and missing fewer months in the other years).

## ksousa

## B. Kelly

## PBH

These three users have consistently maintained their positions in the top 10 list of voters. Although they have been less active in 2023 compared to previous years, they stand out above the rest of the earners of the gold electorate badge because they have never gone very many months  without coming back and writing another question or answer!

---

#### Please join me in thanking everyone, especially the six users for their contributions on this site so far!

While it might be tempting to respond to this post by recognizing me (Nike), my preference would be that you channel that energy into helping to clear the [unanswered queue](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/unanswered), voting on more posts, and helping to edit the typos and formatting errors from some of our users that need more help in those areas (this is a thankless job of which Tyberius and I have been doing the majority, but it is a ***very much needed*** job because it helps maintain the high standards that we have here, and its because of our great reputation that people who are searching for solutions to their problem using Google, are most likely to click on MMSE results rather than on search results from other places!). I really don't need 1 ounce of recognition for anything I've done here, just please help this site grow by encouraging more participation (e.g. by upvoting appropriate content!) and by helping us maintain our reputation as a good place to get questions answered (by clearing the unanswered queue!).

Comment: Hopefully next time we'll have more people that have both the electorate badge ***and*** the fanatic badge (and eventually also the copy editor and marshal badges)!